# Adding a general line in a plot with several levels (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a line in the following plot representing the population growth rate of the five countries analyzed (Argentina + Brazil + Mexico + Spain + USA). This information should also be displayed in the legends (let’s say, “General growth rate”).

To clarify, "General growth rate" would reflect the sum of the population of the five countries by year.

Thanks for the help!

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data("population")

df <- population %>% 
  filter(between(year, 2000, 2010) & country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil", "Mexico", "Spain", "United States of America")) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(pct = 100*population/sum(population))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = pct, col = country)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"), 
                     limits = c(8.25, 9.75)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2000, 2010, by = 1)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, linetype = "solid") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "Population growth rate",  
       subtitle = "2000-2010",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Percentage")
```

[image]

Comment: How do you define general population growth rate? Is it a mean? median? something else?

Comment: @NelsonGon, I have edited my post to clarify what I mean by "general population rate". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use the weighted average growth rate.

```
population %>% 
  filter(between(year, 2000, 2010) & country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil", "Mexico", "Spain", "United States of America")) %>% 
  mutate(pct = 100*population/sum(population), .by = country) -> df
  
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = pct, col = country)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%"), 
                     limits = c(8.25, 9.75)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2000, 2010, by = 1)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5, linetype = "solid", lineend = "round") +
  geom_line(data = df |> 
              summarize(pct = sum(population * pct) / sum(population),
                        .by = year) %>%
              mutate(country = "General growth rate"),
            linewidth = 2.5) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "Population growth rate",  
       subtitle = "2000-2010",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Percentage")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jon Spring. Thanks for the help. However, when I ran your syntax, the following issue appeared:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'year' not found

Comment: The .by parameter for summarize/mutate was added around dplyr v1.1.0, are you using a recent version of dplyr?

Comment: I updated dplyr, then the syntax worked fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. First we are grouping by `year` and `country` to calculate the
   changes in population for each country over a range of years (from
   2000 to 2010).
2. We then generate `df_general` data frame to calculate the "general"
   growth rate across all the specified countries for each year.
3. With this we get a baseline of comparison for the individual growth rates of each country.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

df <- population %>% 
  filter(between(year, 2000, 2010) & country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil", "Mexico", "Spain", "United States of America")) %>% 
  group_by(year, country) %>%
  summarise(population = sum(population)) %>%
  mutate(pct = 100 * population / sum(population))

df_general <- df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(total_population = sum(population)) %>%
  mutate(pct_general = 100 * total_population / sum(total_population))
  
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = year, y = pct, color = country)) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = year, y = pct, color = country)) +
  geom_line(data = df_general, aes(x = year, y = pct_general, color = "Overall", linetype = "Overall")) +
  labs(title = "Yearly Population Growth Rate",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Growth Rate (%)") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("Argentina" = "red", "Brazil" = "blue", "Mexico" = "green", "Spain" = "purple", "United States of America" = "orange", "Overall" = "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("Overall" = "dashed")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$year), max(df$year), by = 1), labels = as.integer)+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: I am skeptical that the US population grew 44% every year, which seems to be what this suggests. I think you meant `population / lag(population)` not `population / sum(population)`? And maybe group by country, then year, so after the summarise step it'd still be grouped by country, not by year. I think this is showing what share of total population each country represented in each year, which answers a different question.